# Is there a simple way to fill in a grungy font to make it solid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, font-design, fill

I'm looking to make the entire letter solid. I want to complete the grungy white space and fill it out with solid black. Is there a simple way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Are these actual fonts? Is it a path? Is it a raster image? Do you want to make a new font family? Do you have the licence of the font?

Answer (score 2):

For the bulk of it....

Select **only** the outer path and that counter (hole) where the strokes cross. You'll have to use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow). Just click-drag outside the shape until you barely touch the edge.

Choose `Object > Lock` from the menu.

Still with the Direct Selection tool, click-drag across everything.

Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

Choose `Object > Unlock All` from the menu.

That will *remove* all the internal paths leaving the overall shape. It will ***not*** do anything to alter the outer edge, but it will "fill in" all the internal holes by removing enclosed compound paths.

[image]

The outer edge would need to be redrawn or manually corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Only those holes, that 100% intersect with black fill, can be removed fast.
But grunge on the edges can't be. There is only one way to achieve this with good quality – you need to draw path manually.

Comment: My donr you consider tracing the path easy?

Comment: It's easy, but if you have large amount of objects it would be time consuming.

Comment: Drawing the entire english alphabet, if you have a model, does not take more than a day.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty (not perfect) method is to bring in the image into Photoshop at high resolution (black and white works best). Then apply a good amount gaussian blur to it. Then, apply a Threshold adjustment layer and play with the level. It will make it solid, but you will lose some detail. Then you can use the Burn or Dodge tool on the areas of the font you want to make thinner or heavier.[image]